# unable to insert dynamic rows into table using mysql and nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to insert array of objects into the SQL but getting the following error

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO orderedproducts (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ((19, 10, 2),?,?)'
```

This my testing array of object

```
var testData = [
                  {
                     productId: 10,
                     quantity: 2
                  }
               ]
```

I want to insert this object data into sql.

My current written code which is returning above error

```
let lastId = results.insertId

                    let orderedProductSql = 'INSERT INTO orderedproducts (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)'

                    var testData = [
                        {
                            productId: 10,
                            quantity: 2
                        }
                    ]

                    let values = testData.reduce((o, a) => {
                        let ini = []
                        ini.push(lastId)
                        ini.push(a.productId)
                        ini.push(a.quantity)
                        o.push(ini)
                        return o
                    }, [])

                    connection.query(orderedProductSql, [values], (err, results) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return connection.rollback(_ => {
                                throw err
                            })
                        }
                        connection.commit(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                connection.rollback(_ => {
                                    throw err
                                })
                            }
                            connection.release()
                            callBack(null, results)
                        })
                    })
```

How can I solve this ??

Comment: Your placeholders have been replaced with parameters values only partially. `(19, 10, 2)` was treated as ONE parameter.

Comment: how do i solve that ?? @Akina

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
connection.query( "INSERT INTO orderedproducts SET order_id=?, product_id=?, quantity=?" , [lastid, productid, quantity] , 
  function(err, result) {
     if(err) throw err;
     });
```

You need to use SET to insert data into your mysql database.

Comment: i need to pass dynamic rows. Soo i cant do this way